# How can I send all my VPN outgoing traffic to TOR

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have some Linux VPN servers (they run `Streisand`).

Obviously, when I connect with `OpenVPN` to one of those VPN, my IP address is the VPN's IP.

When I connect to the VPN, I would like to have a TOR IP address at the end.

It would be something like what offers AIRVPN or other VPN providers that, create a virtual network adaptater on my machine, routing all traffic through tor.

So all my applications would work over tor.

To summarize, what I need is :

```
Home --> VPN server --> TOR
```

I only found how to do Home --> Tor --> VPN server...

What should I do on my VPN servers to archieve this, please? Ideally I would like to continue to use `OpenVPN` to connect to my server.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should just run Tor on the local system after connecting to the VPN.

The reason for this is that the Tor data will be encrypted *before* it reaches your VPN server, making the connection between you and the Tor network end-to-end encrypted.

If you set up Tor on the VPN server then the server would see the *plaintext* of traffic you were sending to Tor. It simply adds another place where your connection could be spied upon. If you run the Tor client on the local system then the server will not be able to see the plaintext of your Tor traffic.

In general, VPNs don't provide much protection and can infact be farmful but having a Tor client run at the other side of the connection rather than your own computer would just make you more vulnerable. You should consider why the VPN is necessary at all and what protections you think it is providing and if it is really providing them.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:

1. Connect TOR after connected to VPN = Home --> VPN server --> TOR
2. Set proxy for VPN = Home --> TOR --> VPN server

More information can be found here:

- [Is it recommended that we use a VPN along with Tor?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/19728/19920)
- [VPN or TOR? This is the Problem](https://mstajbakhsh.ir/vpn-or-tor-this-is-the-problem/)

[image: VPN Through TOR]

Answer (score 0):

You would simply connect to your VPN using their client (or by using another client like OpenVPN or WireGurd) and you would start up Tor Browser. Your entire internet traffic will be routed through Your VPN, and everything in Tor Browser will be routed through your VPN and then Tor.